# Combining numbers and letters in equation numbering LaTeX

Tags: equations, numbering

I currently have the following equation in LaTeX:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the following in LaTeX:

[image: equations in first part of section]

The problem is that I can't seem to get the numbering to start at 1a. When I use the following code, it starts at 0a:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\alph{equation}}

\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}
```

I've tried using

```
\setcounter{equation}{1}
```

But that line of code changes where the lettering starts (in this case with 0b).

EDIT: I already have 4 sections in my piece (document class apa); This piece of code is in the 4th section, so technically it would have to start at 4a.

Comment: The number is produced by `\thesection`, which means the number of the current section. If you haven’t started a section before your equations, the number will be zero.

Comment: But what are you really trying to do? What numbering scheme are you trying to implement? Maybe you should use `subequations`.

Comment: I am trying to implement the numbering scheme in the second picture. I have edited my post and edded information about the sections. This piece of code is in my 4th section.

Comment: @JolandaKossakowski: Is the `1`in (1a), &c., the number of the group of equations or the number of a section? It's not quite clear.

Comment: @Bernard: Unfortunately I don't know for sure; I only have the PDF-file. the number (1) in (1a) can be any number for my but 0. Because the piece of code is in my 4th section, I would expect that it starts with 4a, 4b etc..

Comment: @JolandaKossakowski Do you need that scheme in all sections or just in the fourth? For all equations in the section?

Comment: @JolandaKossakowski: If that is the case, then ferahfeza's answer is perfect. If "1" is for "the 1st group of equations in section4", then use a subequations environment, as Canaaerus said.

Answer (score 20):

You should use the `subequations` environment provided by `amsmath` for this.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{1st subequation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\section{2nd subequation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\section{No subequation}

\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}

\section{3rd subequation}

Here we want to start again from 4.
\setcounter{equation}{3}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How do you `\label` and reference a single line of the equation vs. the entire block of equations?

Comment: It's worth noting that `subequations` is not a math environment. You have to create number equations within that environment using the `equation` or `align` environments, which are then labeled using the same number and incrementing letters. You can also include text in `subequations` between equations. To answer my previous question, you place a `\label` for the entire `subequations` at the start of the environment and `\labels` for individual equations within those equations.

Answer (score 4):

Set `\setcounter{equation}{0}` in every section:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\alph{equation}}
\begin{document}

\section{a}

\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}

\section{b}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}

\section{c}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}

\section{d}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

According to your last comments:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{a}

\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\section{b}

\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}

\section{c}

\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}

\section{d}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\alph{equation}}
\begin{align}
\text{Level 1}&: y_{mdi} = \mu_{di} + e_{mdi}\\
\text{Level 2}&: \mu_{di} = \mu_i + r_{0di}\\
\text{Level 3}&: \mu_i = \gamma_{000} + u_{00i}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By changing the document class in article your solution works, thank you very much!